# Rails Activemailer with RabbitMQ (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rabbitmq

I am running a Ruby on Rails application, presently using delayed_job to send emails. But I want to switch to RabbitMQ messaging queue. I am not able to find any useful resource to get started with it. I read many RabbitMQ docs and what not. Please get me some heads up to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ integrations for Rails heavily depend on eventmachine and callback-based code. This will make your code really complex, and you will need to make all your code aware of the event loop.

For instance, you can't use the same code if you deploy behind thin (which already has a running event loop) or behind unicorn (in which you have to instantiate a reactor and manage its lifecycle).

On the other side, you can abstract this to an actual job queue (Resque is already much faster than DJ, Sidekiq smokes its pants off, and Beanstalkd/Stalker is a very good contender) which is probably going to be compatible to the `Rails.queue` abstraction in rails 4.

In Rails 4, you have also the option to configure all ActionMailer to be async by default (thereby delegating to any configured job queue). http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ruby/2012/06/26/rails-4-sneak-peek-async-actionmailer.html

Comment: This answer isn't entirely true, or maybe has just become dated. -- Ampq gem relied on event machine. Bunny which is what you should be using now, has its own io loop, done in a separate thread. Its solid. https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny

Comment: Interesting @thrice801. Notice that the answer is from 2 years ago. Please if you find an easy queuing library for instance that can be implemented or wrapped as an ActiveJob provider, add a new answer and send me a msg, I'll upvote it and study the code with great pleasure!

Comment: ya I figured. Regarding library, see comment below but TBH I wouldnt use rabbit for "jobs" if you need job reliability and retry. Message acknowledgement does not really cut it, as when a consumer fails, those unacknowledged jobs remain unacked until process restarts and you cant just send it back to the queue and release as it would yield infinite pushing back to queue and pull off+failing -- see http://grokbase.com/t/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-discuss/137ts15m5r/push-to-back-of-queue-on-nack for more

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to kill 2 birds with one stone, and your sending an email needs are based on active record lifecycle events (which they almost always are), you should check out my gem.

https://github.com/jasonayre/active_pubsub

It was built on the bunny gem and works much like active record observers, except you run the subscribers in a separate process. (this is actually just a bonus functionality, its intended largely to allow multiple rails apps to subscribe to each others events) -- I.E.

```
#user model
class User < ::ActiveRecord::Base
  include ::ActivePubsub::Publishable

  publish_as "myapp"
end

#subscriber

class PostSubscriber < ::ActivePubsub::Subscriber
  observes "cms"
  as "aggregator"

  on :created do |user_hash|
    user = User.find(user_hash[:id])
    #or whatever
    WelcomeMailer.deliver(user)
  end
end
```

== async delivery + keeps your controllers slimmer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a great Ruby background jobs processing library to replace delayed_job you should give [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) a try. There even is a recent Railscast about it [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq).

You can get an overview on [Background Jobs Gems](http://www.knight.io/categories/background-jobs-ruby) on Knight.io (I started this site).

Comment: hi I am aware of this gem, but I am more particular about RabbitMQ

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish something else than sending emails in the background?